# If I make a new original file system, can I MOUNT it with linux?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, linux-kernel

Suppose that I make a new original file system, say `myfs`. Then, can I mount a partition formatted by `myfs`? If yes, what do I need to do for that?

In fact, I'm not going to make a file system. Even if I make a file system, maybe it will be a very primitive and inefficient one. So, this question doesn't have a practical purpose. I just want to know what is needed to mount a file system, and how Linux handles file systems.

In my understanding, Linux kernel can't manage `NTFS`, but `ntfs-3g` enables us to mount `NTFS`. So, I wonder I can mount `myfs` if I make a command like `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask - "_You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face_"